# Failed to precompile JLD

Tags: julia

I had a code that used to work using Julia 0.6, and I have been recently trying to use it again, however I am having different troubles using JLD. 
I tried to use the most recent Julia version and it still does not work.
In 0.6 version, here is what I have :

```
using JLD
```

> INFO: Precompiling module JLD. WARNING: could not import
>   Base.lastindex into HDF5 WARNING: could not import Base.iterate into
>   HDF5 ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Module Libdl not found in
>   current path. Run `Pkg.add("Libdl")` to install the Libdl package.

```
Pkg.add("Libdl")
```

> ERROR: unknown package Libdl

I don't really understand what is going on, I saw similar problems on the Julia blog and also in stackoverflow but no proposed solutions seem to work in my case.. I would be ok to modidify my code si it could work with a newer version of Julia but I still can't make JLD work in any version.

Any advice?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Julia 1.0.0 use the package `JLD2.jl`.

Press `]` to go to the package manager:
`add JLD2`

Sample code:

```
using JLD2
obja = (a=5, b=[1,2,3]);
objb = "hello world";
save("dat.jld2","obja",obja,"objb",objb);
```

Now running

```
load("dat.jld2")
```

yields

```
Dict{String,Any} with 2 entries:
  "obja" => (a = 5, b = [1, 2, 3])
  "objb" => "hello world"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this but I also would like not to change my whole code and therefore being able to run it on former versions of julia. Do you know if there is a way to fix the problem on the former versions of Julia by any chance?

Comment: JLD is not any longer supported in favour of JLD2 so I would say you have to update your code. Fortunately the API looks to be the same so it does not seem to be a big deal...

Comment: Yes I'll do that then. When I copy and past your code into Julia 1.0 I obtain : 
> ERROR: UndefVarError: save not defined 
and when I try `JLD2.save("dat.jld2","obja",obja,"objb",objb);` I obtain :
> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching save(::String, ::String, ::NamedTuple{(:a, :b),Tuple{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}}, ::String, ::String) 
`Using FileIO
FileIO.save()`
works for me. Thanks for your answer!